# Chrome Browser window is not maximize in Selenium-grid node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

Windows are not maximize issue occurs only in grid node.
we tried the different methods to get it resolved as shown below, but nothing has worked

```java
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(1920,1080)
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
driver.manage().window().maximize()
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

NOTE: No issue observed when we run the scripts locally , or if i logged into that node when the scripts is running, but when I close that node, and start the script, then window size would remain small and couldn't find some webElement

Answer (score 0):

Maximize the browser with Java :

`driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Another way to do with Java:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenResolution = new Dimension((int) 
                    toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int) 
                    toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight());

driver.manage().window().setSize(screenResolution);
```

Comment: we tried all above, but didn't worked.
What we observed is after establishing the RDP connection and closing it, the windows maximise is working as expected